# iOS Swift: Custom status bar button for returning to the app

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I‘m making an iOS Swift App with UIKit and SwiftUI which includes a turn-by-turn navigation (with mapbox). Now what I want is, that when the user exits the app during a navigation, the typical blue button over the time appears (or something for the dynamic island) to return to the navigation easily.

[right after you exit the e.g. Google Maps, Waze, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovggJ.jpg)

[After a couple of seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEbrE.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You'll have to implement deep linking in your app so that when location services are active you app can automatically open up your map view.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you might want to look into [showsBackgroundLocationIndicator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/2923541-showsbackgroundlocationindicator)

Comment: Kind of what I was looking for - is there a way to make this more customizable?